# NodeJS MySQL blob upload is slow - bypass MySQL blob conversion process with NodeJS buffer

Tags: mysql, node.js, blob

I am uploading some images to a blob in MySQL but every time I upload it is very slow. I tried uploading the plain text vs. converting the text to a buffer before uploading and both ways seem like they are just as slow as the other but I have a feeling that converting is faster. I am using NodeJS and uploading with the fileReader result value on the client. Is there any way I can make uploading faster on the server? I am thinking that if I insert the buffer, the MySQL blob will be able to read that a buffer is being inserted and wont attempt to convert it like it would a string. Is there a way to bypass the conversion process of a MySQL blob so I can upload faster? ..Or does the conversion happen quickly and is it something else that is slowing down the insertion?

```
  if(req.body.product_images.length == 0) { 
    req.body.product_images = null;
  } else {
    req.body.product_images = req.body.product_images.join('***img_separator***'); //string upload
    req.body.product_images = Buffer.from(req.body.product_images, 'utf-8'); //buffer upload 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8??  An image is *not* characters; it is `BLOB` or `BINARY`, and needs to be handled differently.  Perhaps the best way to pass an image around is via Base64.

If the image is used on a web page, don't put it in the database.  Instead, store it in a file and store the URL to it in the database.  Then build `<img src=...>` in the HTML to reference it at load time.

**Opaque string**

To look at it from the database perspective:  You have an 'opaque' string of bytes.  The db does not need to care what is in it, so you just want the most efficient way to insert/fetch.  `BLOB` (or perhaps `MEDIUMBLOB`) is fine.

If using `TEXT`, `CHARACTER SET ascii` would be optimal and `COLLATE ascii_bin` would be optimal and appropriate for BASE64.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I create the base64 string on the client and upload that to the server. I did not know if converting it to an array buffer to store as a blob would be more efficient inserting than inserting the string itself. In terms of the file, yes I plan on using a standard file to store the long string but I am trying to figure out the correct file type if you know. I am storing many images per file.

Comment: @JohnathanM - "many images per file" -- How to you plan to split them apart?  "many images per database table" -- one per row?

Comment: I am concatenating each image together with a string. One set of images per row with the id in the db as a reference to the file where the images will be stored. Just not sure which type of file to use.

Comment: @JohnathanM - The "concatenating" sounds like a mistake.

Comment: Im storing multiple product images per file. the file is a base64 string concatenated with other base64 strings that represent pictures. Its pretty simple. Why would it be a mistake? I know how to do the other way too but it just make things easier.

Comment: @JohnathanM - I added to my answer.